# vba msgbox tied to conditional formatting, worksheet has multiple strings

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting, msgbox

I currently have a workbook that I have created that already has VBA msgbox code input for 2 specific cells. However, I need to add additional text box code for 2 additional cells that have conditional formatting already in place. 
Currently the conditional formatting changes the cell color to green if "no" is selected on the drop down menu, and it turns red if "yes" is selected.

I need to create a msgbox code, only when "yes" is selected, with vbcaution msgbox pop-up.

I have tried using VBYesNo code, however, this seems to tie into VBbuttons and not was I am looking for. Additionally, since this sheet already has code written specifically to other cells not related to this needed function. How I do I create extra code, to where I will not have a compiling or syntax error?

The current code that is already in place for this sheet that I cannot have the additional code interfere with is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim C As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D11:D13")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each C In Intersect(Target, Range("D11:D13"))
            Select Case C.Value2
                Case "Kansas", "KS"
                    MsgBox "Test 1"
                Case "Ohio", "OH"
                    MsgBox "Test 2"
                Case "New York", "NY"
                    MsgBox "Test 3"
            End Select
        Next C
    End If
End Sub
```

I would like the code to only issue the msgbox when "yes" is selected for cells D17 and D21, and need for it not to create a compiling or syntax error due to the msgbox code that is already written and in place for this workbook.

Comment: Are these data validation dropdowns? Looks like you just need another check of the value of D17 and D21. Not sure what you mean by "VBbuttons"?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will not interfere with your other code. I have included both pieces of new code and your original code into one vba script.

So that the code will function correctly, event triggers for both D17 and D21 require separating, otherwise if D17 is already populated with "Yes" and then a change is made to D21, the event change will be triggered because of D17 value and vice versa.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Ans As Variant
Dim C As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D17")) Is Nothing Then

If Range("D17").Value = "Yes" Then

    Ans = MsgBox("Your warning goes here.", vbYesNo)

       Select Case Ans
            Case vbYes
                ' If Yes then the yes code goes here

            Case vbNo
                ' If No then the yes code goes here
        End Select

    End If

End If


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D21")) Is Nothing Then

    If Range("D21").Value = "Yes" Then

        Ans = MsgBox("Your warning goes here.", vbYesNo)

        Select Case Ans
            Case vbYes
                ' If Yes then the yes code goes here

            Case vbNo
                ' If No then the yes code goes here
        End Select

    End If

End If

' Your piece of code:

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D11:D13")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each C In Intersect(Target, Range("D11:D13"))
        Select Case C.Value2
            Case "Kansas", "KS"
                MsgBox "Test 1"
            Case "Ohio", "OH"
                MsgBox "Test 2"
            Case "New York", "NY"
                MsgBox "Test 3"
        End Select
    Next C
End If

End Sub
```